# Accepting donations from Non-Shomer Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, tzedakah-charity, organizations, non-religious

May a Torah institution accept funds from a Jew who makes money from working on Shabbos? (I heard that a particular Rebbe collecting money would put money earned with holy endeavors was put into his right pocket, less holy intentions in his left pocket, and earned on shabbos in his back pocket - which he would eventually burn)

Of course CYLOR when the question actually arises